# Cannot delete files

Tags: permissions, fstab, symbolic-link

I've got my documents directory mounted on a separate partition from /home (/mnt/data) and linked symbolically. If I try to delete anything from ~/Documents via the GUI the window simply closes and the document is not deleted. However, "rm" works just fine from the CLI.

/etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=106ff40f-5721-431a-a20b-e4a550a5baea /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--gnome--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0

# /DATA is on sdb2
#<Device>                   <Mountpoint>    <FStype>    <Options>       <Dump>   < Pass>
UUID=95352c25-edb4-47a8-b36d-ee88e299bb10   /mnt/data   ext4        defaults    0   2
```

ls Documents:

```
~$ ls -ld /mnt/data/stephen/Documents
drwxr-xr-x 12 stephen stephen 4096 Feb 21 12:30 /mnt/data/stephen/Documents
```

A file I created as an example:

```
:~$ ls -l ~/Documents/example.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephen stephen 0 Feb 21 12:33 /home/stephen/Documents/example.txt
```

If I do exactly the same things in ~, I can delete the file through the GUI without issue.

~ permission:

```
:~$ ls -ld ~
drwxr-xr-x 33 stephen stephen 4096 Feb 21 12:35 /home/stephen
```

I suspect a problem with my folder permissions over /mnt/data/stephen, can anyone see what I've done wrong?

EDIT:
Found this:

```
:~$ ls -ld ~/Documents
lrwxrwxrwx 1 stephen stephen 27 Jan  5 18:48 /home/stephen/Documents -> /mnt/data/stephen/Documents
```

Does this look right?

FURTHER EDIT:
Launched Nautilus from the CLI and tried deleting the example.txt file, got this error:

```
*** Error in `nautilus': double free or corruption (out): 0x00007f59380075a0 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

ls -ld /mnt/data:

```
:~$ ls -ld /mnt/data
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Jan  5 18:39 /mnt/data
```

Comment: I don't see anything particularly odd about that last output.

Comment: What about `$ ls -l /mnt/data` ?